# Pyodbc: Login Timeout Error

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to MS SQL Server using `pyodbc` from a remote machine running Ubuntu 16.04.

```
import pyodbc 

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server; SERVER=xxxTest-SRV; PORT=51333; DATABASE=TestDB; UID=xxxx; PWD=xxxx;')
```

I'm getting following error:

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)')

I tried using the server `IP` in the connection string but still no luck.

However, I am able to connect to using `sqlcmd` from the terminal
Following works:

```
sqlcmd -S xxxTest-SRV, 51333 -d TestDB -U xxxx -P xxxx
```

I didn't find any issue that gave an answer to my problem.

***odbcinst.ini***

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.1.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
```

There's always seems to be an issue connecting to MS SQL Server using `pyodbc` from a linux machine. Is there a way to connect to SQL Server from Python. I'll appreciate your help in solving this error. Thank you.

**[UPDATE]**

As per the below answer, I updated the connection string. But, now I get following error:

> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open
>   lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.0.so.1.1' : file
>   not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

My ***odbcinst.ini*** file driver definition:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.0.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
```

It has always been a nightmare to connect to MS SQL Server from a Linux machine. Can you please tell which `pyodbc`, `unixODBC` and `Driver` version is the most stable?

I have installed the driver following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) Microsoft instructions. My `pyodbc` version is `4.0.23`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Microsoft's ODBC drivers for SQL Server do not use a `PORT=` parameter. The port number, if any, is appended to the server name/IP with a comma, e.g.,

```
SERVER=xxxTest-SRV,51333;
```

Comment: I changed that and now I'm getting this `pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.0.so.1.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")` error

Comment: I uninstalled `Microsoft ODBC Driver 17` and installed `Microsoft ODBC Driver 13`, then I made the change you suggested in your answer and it worked. Thank you and I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal: were you still able to use `sqlcmd` after you down-graded to ODBC 13? I'm finding that the `mssql-tools` package currently requires version 17, which is highly annoying.

Comment: @GordThompson: This solution didn't work for me; I'm working on a few options like getting ports opened up. That may be the issue.

Comment: @AdrianKeister - Yes, I was. After using`msodbc` drivers 13 and 17 thus far, I would say that the main care that needs to be taken is to make sure that there no two versions installed and if you have them installed then you need to configure with `odbc.ini` accordingly.

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal: Good to know, thanks! Where does the odbc.ini file go in, say, Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: @AdrianKeister: It should be in `/opt/` directory. Have you checked this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017. Follow this guide to install `unixODBC` for SQL Server on your machine. It is quite a comprehensive guide to help you set it up.

Comment: Uninstalling `Microsoft ODBC Driver 17` and installing `Microsoft ODBC Driver 13` worked for me. Thank you so much. @Krishnang K Dalal

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same kind of issue, but my scenario is connecting to SQL server hosted on ec2 instance through AWS Lambda function using PyOdbc module. For me, replacing the host name with IP address of ec2 instance fixed it.

I found out that it was not able to resolve dns. So if any of the above steps didn't work for you, please try using the ip address and comment here

Comment: I had the same issue running Airflow in Docker. Replacing the server name by the IP address resolved the issue.

Comment: I am running CentOS and using Pypyodbc. All I did was replace the server name with its IP address and it worked. Thanks Steven Van Dorpe!

Comment: can you please give the syntax?

Comment: replacing hostname with ipaddress worked thanks

Answer (score 5):

I ran into same problem when working with SQL Server docker container inside VS Code development container. Finding the IP of SQL Server container (credits for that goes to [freecodecamp.org How to get docker container IP address](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-a-docker-container-ip-address-explained-with-examples/)) and replacing server name with IP solved the problem

```
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
            "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};" + "SERVER=172.xx.x.x;"
            "DATABASE=xxx;"
            "UID=sa;"
            "PWD=xxx;")
```

Comment: The link saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

Placing this here in case it helps someone with a similar situation to mine:

For me the fix was a network issue that wasn't allowing my Ubuntu machine to resolve the name of the SQL Server to it's IP address. Discovered this from getting returned `Temporary failure in name resolution` after attempting to ping the SQL Server by host name.

I connected successfully if I replaced with IP, but the best solution was to correct the Ubuntu server's network configuration with the help of the Network Admins. According to them the name server settings were incorrectly configured on the vlan that the Ubuntu server was a part of.

Answer (score 1):

What solved in my case was to configure in the "SQL Configuration Manager" --> SQL Server Network Configuration --> Protocols for XYX --> TCP/IP --> Properties --> IP Addresses --> IPAII (Here set empty in TCP Dynamic Ports and 1433 (or the port that you want to use) at TCP Port)

You can have more details [here](https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/)

Comment: Thanks for you post and link. it's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's ODBC drivers for Linux cannot resolve instance names, so this won't work from a Linux client:

```
Server      = mydbserver.mycompany.com\SQLEXPRESS
```

If you need to connect to a named instance you can use the (free) sqlserverport (https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlserverport) module.

```
import pyodbc
import sqlserverport
servername = 'myserver'
serverspec = '{0},{1}'.format(
    servername,
    sqlserverport.lookup(servername, 'SQLEXPRESS'))
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER={};...'.format(serverspec))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to connect to mssql for sqlalchemy from linux environment, first tried with:

**Host name connection**:-

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@myhost:port/databasename?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server")
```

which doesn't work for me,so, as an alternate I tried with:

**Pass through exact Pyodbc string**

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
connection_string = "DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=myserver;DATABASE=test;UID=user;PWD=password"
connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
```

and it works for me.
And also as a note, for linux environment one has to additionally install the **odbc driver**

Here is the link for odbc driver:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16