# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am unable to make a connection to the SQL server from Unix using python.

I will not be able to replace the driver from ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server to ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server as explained in [Pyodbc: Login Timeout Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046158/pyodbc-login-timeout-error) due to other dependencies.

Can somebody please suggest an alternative?

CODE:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

from urllib import parse as db_parse

from sqlalchemy import event

params = db_parse.quote_plus(r"DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='server,port';DATABASE=DB_NAME;username=USER_ID;password=PWD;Trusted_Connection=yes")

engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params))

connection = engine.connect()
```

ERROR:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: That answer says **nothing** about downgrading. There's nothing wrong with the ODBC version. The OP was missing a library in that comment and chose downgrade instead of installing the missing library.

Comment: `Trusted_Connection=yes` means Windows Authentication which can't be used on Linux. You can't use that *and* a SQL login in the same connection string. What does the *actual* connection string look like? There could be a real timeout error, or it could be a problem caused by an incorrect value. For example `SERVER='server,port'` is wrong, the server name and port don't need quoting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My connection string looks different:

`"DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=myserver;DATABASE=mydb;UID=myuser;PWD=mypassword"`

leeds to

```
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=myserver;DATABASE=mydb;UID=myuser;PWD=mypassword", autocommit=True)
```

Instead of UID you are using username, etc. All words starting with 'my' have to be replaced with the actual db, user and password. You should also remove the `Trusted_Connection=True;`part as Panagiotis Kanavos pointed out in the comment. This says you are using your windows-user to authenticate (which is obviously not available on linux).

Comment: If you are still available I am facing an issue on doing the same procedure