# Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

Tags: python, sql-server, database, amazon-web-services, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc

details = {
 'server' : 'X.rds.amazonaws.com',
 'database' : 'X',
 'username' : 'X',
 'password' : 'X',
 }

# drivers = [item for item in pyodbc.drivers()]
# driver = drivers[-1]
# print("driver:{}".format(driver))

connect_string = 'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER={server}; DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password})'.format(**details)

connection = pyodbc.connect(connect_string)
print(connection, "printing connection")

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row)
```

I have been trying to solve this for hours now. For some reason, I am unable to connect and fetch output from sql server (hosted in rds-aws).

I am getting this error

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I am running this code from ubuntu 18.04. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: (I am new to DBs) Will this have anything to do with inbound/outbound rules?

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but remove the space before `DATABASE` and get rid of the final closing parenthesis (`)`) after `{password}` in your connection string.

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you for the tip, but it did not work. Getting the same error.

Comment: Okay. I've never used AWS but I do know that some cloud services require (or can be configured to require) that IP addresses be whitelisted before they are allowed to connect. Have you looked into that?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046158/pyodbc-login-timeout-error

Comment: @GordThompson I could not find the root cause. Instead I created a new aws-rds instance and loaded the DB in the new instance and set public accessibility 'ON'. Earlier as well, I had used the same settings, but somehow it never worked. Nevertheless I have it working now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Alex Thank you. Had tried it already. Did not work.